# CloudFormation BucketPolicy stuck at CREATE. Never finished CREATE

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

Cloud forming an S3 bucket with user, user access keys, and policy. It should create the stack and output the user access keys needed to work with the created S3 bucket via the SDK. Bucket Policy gets stuck in the CREATING phase forever when trying to reference the BucketUser ARN in the BucketPolicy Principal.

CloudFormation is successful with

`BucketPolicy: ... Principal: "*"`

But BucketPolicy resource is stuck in CREATE forever with

`BucketPolicy: ... Principal: !GetAtt BucketUser.Arn`

This successfully returns the BucketUser.Arn when `BucketPolicy: ... Principal: "*"`

```
Outputs:
  BucketUserArn:
    Value: !GetAtt BucketUser.Arn
```

Desired Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Creates bucket with bucket policy"
#Metadata: 
Parameters:
  app:
    Type: String
    Description: (required) Application name (Also used for bucket name. Follow S3 bucket name conventions)
    Default: ymessage-bucket-test
Resources:
  BucketUser:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::User"
    Properties: 
      UserName: !Ref app
  UserAccessKey:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::AccessKey"
    Properties: 
      Status: Active
      UserName: !Ref app
    DependsOn: BucketUser
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref app
  BucketPolicy:
      Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
      Properties: 
        Bucket: !Ref app
        PolicyDocument: 
          Statement: 
            - 
              Action: 
                - "s3:*"
              Effect: "Allow"
              Resource: 
                Fn::Join: 
                  - ""
                  - 
                    - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                    - !Ref app
                    - "/*"
              Principal: !GetAtt BucketUser.Arn
      DependsOn: BucketUser
Outputs:
  AccessKeyId:
    Value: !Ref UserAccessKey
  AccessKeySecret:
    Value: !GetAtt UserAccessKey.SecretAccessKey
  BucketURL:
    Value: !GetAtt Bucket.WebsiteURL
  BucketUserArn:
    Value: !GetAtt BucketUser.Arn
```

Working Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Creates bucket with bucket policy"
#Metadata: 
Parameters:
  app:
    Type: String
    Description: (required) Application name (Also used for bucket name. Follow S3 bucket name conventions)
    Default: ymessage-bucket-test
Resources:
  BucketUser:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::User"
    Properties: 
      UserName: !Ref app
  UserAccessKey:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::AccessKey"
    Properties: 
      Status: Active
      UserName: !Ref app
    DependsOn: BucketUser
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref app
  BucketPolicy:
      Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
      Properties: 
        Bucket: !Ref app
        PolicyDocument: 
          Statement: 
            - 
              Action: 
                - "s3:*"
              Effect: "Allow"
              Resource: 
                Fn::Join: 
                  - ""
                  - 
                    - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                    - !Ref app
                    - "/*"
              Principal: "*"
      DependsOn: BucketUser
Outputs:
  AccessKeyId:
    Value: !Ref UserAccessKey
  AccessKeySecret:
    Value: !GetAtt UserAccessKey.SecretAccessKey
  BucketURL:
    Value: !GetAtt Bucket.WebsiteURL
  BucketUserArn:
    Value: !GetAtt BucketUser.Arn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example of a S3 bucket policy giving cross account access.
Note the quotes in "version" and "actions", and the "AWS" key under "Principal", under which the list of principals are defined. This was added to serverless script which had bucket name in environment available. Change to suit your script.

```
MyBucketPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket: ${self:provider.environment.MY_BUCKET}
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Action:
            - 's3:GetObject'
            - 's3:PutObjectAcl'
            - 's3:GetBucketLocation'
            - 's3:GetObjectTagging'
            - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
            - 's3:ListBucket'
            - 's3:ListBucketVersions'
          Effect: Allow
          Resource:
            - arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.MY_BUCKET}
            - arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.MY_BUCKET}/*
          Principal:
            AWS:
              - arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID_1:root
              - arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID_2:root
              - arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID_3:root
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: In the BucketPolicy it can directly accept `Principal: "*"` but if you want to use an arn do this:

```
Principal: 
  AWS: 
    - !GetAtt BucketUser.Arn
```